# practical use prototype.constructor in javascript

Tags: javascript

In Simple words why we use `prototype.constructor`. I am reading an article about inheritance where I saw `prototype.constructor`. I see no difference in result when I comment that code. So my question why and when to use it practically.

```
function Mammal(name){ 
    this.name=name;
  this.action= function (){
  alert('0')
  }

} 



function Cat(name){ 
    this.name=name;
} 

Cat.prototype = new Mammal();

//Cat.prototype.constructor=Cat; // Otherwise instances of Cat would have a constructor of Mammal 



Cat.prototype.action=function(){
alert('1')
}

var y= new Mammal()
var x= new Cat()

y.action()

x.action()
```

Comment: — The `constructor`  property is generally not in used. it's just supply _information_ for which function constructor the related object was created from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>It's mostly convention. Although nothing in JavaScript itself uses the `constructor` property, sometimes people use it in their code, assuming that it will refer back to the object's constructor.</s> It's not just convention anymore, see ¹ for details.

When you create a function:

```
function Cat() {
}
```

The function starts out with an object on its `prototype` property that has a property called `constructor` that points back to the function:

```
console.log(Cat.prototype.constructor === Cat); // true
```

This is in the specification. (<s>It's also the **only** place in the specification that property is mentioned — e.g., JavaScript, itself, makes no use of this property at all.</s> Not anymore.¹)

Consequently, instances created with that prototype (whether created via the constructor function or other ways) inherit that `constructor` property:

```
var c = new Cat();
console.log(c.constructor === Cat);  // true

var c2 = Object.create(Cat.prototype);
console.log(c2.constructor === Cat); // true, even though Cat wasn't used
```

When you replace the `prototype` property on a function, as you typically do when building hierarchies:

```
Cat.prototype = new Mammal(); // This is an anti-pattern, btw, see below
```

...you end up with an object on `Cat.prototype` where `constructor` points to `Mammal`. Since that's not what one normally expects, it's customary to fix it:

```
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;
```

<s>Although nothing in JavaScript itself uses the property</s> (it does now¹), sometimes people use it in their code, assuming that it will refer back to the object's constructor.

---

Re the anti-pattern in that code: When using constructor functions to build a hierarchy, it's not best practice to actually *call* the "base" constructor to create the "derived" constructor's `prototype`. Instead, use `Object.create` to create the prototype:

```
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Mammal.prototype);
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;
```

...and then chain to `Mammal` in `Cat`:

```
function Cat() {
    Mammal.call(this);
    // ...
}
```

Why do it that way? Consider: What if the base requires arguments you won't get until construction-time to meaningfully initialize an instance? You can't pass it arguments until you have them. The pattern above allows you to handle that situation.

Note that `Object.create` was added in ES5 and so is missing from some old browsers (like IE8). The single-argument version of it can be shimmed/polyfilled trivially, though:

```
if (!Object.create) {
    Object.create = function(proto, props) {
        if (typeof props !== "undefined") {
            throw new Error("The second argument of Object.create cannot be shimmed.");
        }
        function f() { }
        f.prototype = proto;
        return new f;
    };
}
```

---

I'll just note that constructor functions are just *one way* of building object hierarchies in JavaScript. They're not the only way, because JavaScript uses prototypical inheritance. JavaScript is so powerful you *can* use constructor functions to get something similar to class-like inheritance, but it also lets you do more traditional prototypical-style inheritance directly.

---

¹ *"Although nothing in JavaScript itself uses the `constructor` property..."* That's not true anymore as of ES2015 (aka "ES6"). Now, the `constructor` property is used in a couple of places (such as  the [SpeciesConstructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-speciesconstructor) and [ArraySpeciesCreate](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-arrayspeciescreate) abstract operations), which are used in various classes that have methods returning new instances of the class, such as `Array#slice` and `Promise#then`. It's used in those places to ensure that subclasses work correctly: E.g., if you subclass `Array`, and use `slice` on an instance of the subclass, the array returned by `slice` is an instance of your subclass, not a raw `Array` — because `slice` uses ArraySpeciesCreate.